# Unable to deploy React app with Vercel "sh: webpack: command not found'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vercel

I have a frontend React app deployed with Vercel, the repo is on Github. Previously all the process was fine, every time I push some update on the repo Vercel redeploys it and my website was up-to-date.

But now the deployment crash returning error `sh: webpack: command not found`. I don't understand because `webpack` is present in devDependencies on my `package.json`, on my machine everything works well from `npm i`, `npm run build` and `npm run dev`.

I understand that during the build process of Vercel despite that installation went well, the build command crash with error 127 couldn't find webpack.

Logs from Vercel:

```
Previous build cache not available
Cloning completed: 695.423ms
Not using Build Cache
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 28.4.15
Running "install" command: `npm i`...
added 46 packages, and audited 47 packages in 4s
1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
found 0 vulnerabilities
> konflx-todolist@1.0.0 build
> echo 'Building webpack dist folder' && rm -rf dist && webpack --mode production --env production
Building webpack dist folder
sh: webpack: command not found
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 127
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "konflx-todolist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "echo 'Building webpack dist folder' && rm -rf dist && webpack --mode production --env production",
    "dev": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js",
    "testDev": "webpack-dev-server --https"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "konflex",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bulma": "^0.9.4",
    "css-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
    "sass": "^1.56.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@iconicicons/react": "^1.5.0",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.15.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "framer-motion": "^7.3.5",
    "rc-pagination": "^3.1.17",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

My machine run on `node v18.12.1` and `npm 8.19.2`, I updated both recently. I downgrade then for the same result. Any clue ?

Comment: You are trying to run `webpack` as a linux command. It does not matter it you have it in your devDependencies. You have to run it as an `NPM` script by adding something like `"prod": "webpack --mode production --env production`" in `package.json` "scripts" and use `npm run prod` instead.

Comment: In Vercel, you can define command and for the build I use `npm run build` so I guess it is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vercel when you pass `--mode production` in `webpack` the `devDependencies` are not installed. By just calling `webpack` it solved the issue. If you want to use production mode, you must install all devDependencies to be able to build your project.

Comment: Why are you building on vercel, not on your computer and then deploying dist on vercel?